# JNI 8 C++ : Thread attach and detach And async callback

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, asynchronous, java-native-interface

How to async call Java method from std::thread ?

Let's assuming this is a IM bot sdk, Because it's logic basicly a IM bot sdk.

The most importtant is: How to async call java method and callback native.

There is logic flow at the bottom, Maybe helpful.

For example:

Receive message A "backup", Then call the java plugin with MsgA, The plugin porcess this event need 10second, And call 5 time native method for what ever it need.

Mean while, Receive message B "echo", That only take 10ms to process, And send an message by invoke native method.

So, MsgB recived after MsgA, But finish befor MsgA.

If using pure C C++ java or what ever, That will be so easy to achive. But here I found a headache problem: JNI thread Attach.

※ First question: Wired JNI attach

I have read doc find answer, None of them working and my condition different with everyone

I'm using Zulu JDK8 (zulu8.48.0.53-ca-fx-jdk8.0.265-win_x64) and MinGW64 C++, For demo:

```java
public class ThreadTest {

    private static int count = 0;

    private static final Random random = new Random();

    public static int count() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count++;
    }
    
}
```

Here is the worker function in C++

```cpp
void worker(JNIEnv* localEnv) {
    jclass clazz = localEnv->FindClass("ThreadTest");
    jmethodID method = localEnv->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "count", "()I");
    jchar result = localEnv->CallStaticCharMethod(clazz, method);
    int tid = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());
    printf("[Worker Done] %d =>> %d\n", tid, result);
}
```

And without attach we will get, That is expected:

```cpp
worker(env);
// Here the first call from main thread, Working find;
// [Worker Done] -1444639049 =>> 0

jvm->DetachCurrentThread();

std::thread t1(worker, env);
t1.join();

// Process crashed because not attach jni
// Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

And add the tWorker function for t1:

```cpp
void tWorker (JavaVM* gJvm) {

    int tid = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());

    printf("[Thread Run] %d\n", tid);

    JavaVMAttachArgs* args;
    args->version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    args->name = nullptr;
    args->group = nullptr;

    JNIEnv* lEnv;

    printf("[Attach for] %d\n", tid);
    int attachResult = gJvm->AttachCurrentThread(reinterpret_cast<void**>(lEnv), &args);
    printf("[Attach Done] %d =>> %d\n", tid, attachResult);
    delete args;

    worker(lEnv);

    gJvm->DetachCurrentThread();

}
```

I got this:

```
[Worker Done] -1444639049 =>> 0
[Thread Run] 1709724944

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Some answer say you should use `GetEnv`:

```cpp
void tWorker02(JavaVM* gJvm, JNIEnv* gEnv) {

    int tid = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());

    printf("[Thread Run] %d\n", tid);

    JavaVMAttachArgs* args;
    args->version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    args->name = nullptr;
    args->group = nullptr;

    JNIEnv* lEnv;

    printf("[GetEnv for] %d\n", tid);
    int getEnvResult = gJvm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(lEnv), JNI_VERSION_1_8);
    printf("[GetEnv Done] %d =>> %d\n", tid, getEnvResult);

    printf("[Attach for] %d\n", tid);
    int attachResult = gJvm->AttachCurrentThread(reinterpret_cast<void**>(lEnv), &args);
    printf("[Attach Done] %d =>> %d\n", tid, attachResult);

    delete args;

    worker(gEnv);

    gJvm->DetachCurrentThread();

}
```

Got same result:

```
[Worker Done] -1444639049 =>> 0
[Thread Run] 1709724944

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

For more post I found, Replace Local to Global (That dosen't make any sense for logic and Document but in their question problem solved)

```cpp
    //JNIEnv* lEnv;

    printf("[GetEnv for] %d\n", tid);
    int getEnvResult = gJvm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(gEnv), JNI_VERSION_1_8);
    printf("[GetEnv Done] %d =>> %d\n", tid, getEnvResult);

    printf("[Attach for] %d\n", tid);
    int attachResult = gJvm->AttachCurrentThread(reinterpret_cast<void**>(gEnv), &args);
    printf("[Attach Done] %d =>> %d\n", tid, attachResult);
```

That is usless, Even I try all 16 combination, That not work for me.

```
[Worker Done] -1444639049 =>> 0
[Thread Run] 1709724944

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Question one: What happen in there?

※ Second Question: How to achive that:

[image: Logic flow for what I'm doing]

Update 1:

Question 1 solved.

```cpp
void tWorker02(JavaVM* gJvm, JNIEnv* gEnv) {

    int tid = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());

    printf("[Thread Run] %d\n", tid);

    auto* args = new JavaVMAttachArgs{};
    args->version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    args->name = nullptr;
    args->group = nullptr;

    JNIEnv* lEnv;

    printf("[GetEnv for] %d\n", tid);
    int getEnvResult = gJvm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&args, JNI_VERSION_1_8);
    printf("[GetEnv Done] %d =>> %d\n", tid, getEnvResult);

    if (getEnvResult == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        printf("[Attach for] %d\n", tid);
        int attachResult = gJvm->AttachCurrentThread(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&lEnv), &args);
        printf("[Attach Done] %d =>> %d\n", tid, attachResult);
    }

    delete args;

    worker(gEnv);

    gJvm->DetachCurrentThread();
}
```

Without cast will cause a complie error  `error: invalid conversion from 'JNIEnv**' {aka 'JNIEnv_**'} to 'void**' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Regarding `GetEnv`: You're supposed to check what it returns, and only if it returned `JNI_EDETACHED` should you proceed to call `AttachCurrentThread`. Note that this is for the case where you don't know whether the thread already is attached. If you're 100% sure that the thread isn't already attached, then you can skip `GetEnv`. However, doing an Attach and Detach for every callback can be a bit wasteful, depending on how often these callbacks occur. It might be better to attach each thread once, and detach them when the thread is destroyed.

Comment: @Michael Question 1 solved, But as further test, Multithread `AttachCurrentThread` will cause exit because thread B loot env at thread A. So the `It might be better to attach each thread once, and detach them when the thread is destroyed.` I don't know that mean. (part1/2)

Comment: The hole project based on that module because I have seen an similar SDK with that: Event occure then call C++ thread then JNI call java method, And as plugin developer, Every event woring in isolation threads, One crash won't affect others. And java can take any long time it needed, Response and call back native can be disorder, So is that impossiable in JNI?(part 2/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the your problems are not in usage of JVM but in C++ code. Looking at this piece of code:

```cpp
void tWorker02(JavaVM* gJvm, JNIEnv* gEnv) {

    int tid = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());

    printf("[Thread Run] %d\n", tid);

    JavaVMAttachArgs* args;
    args->version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    args->name = nullptr;
    args->group = nullptr;
```

Pay attention here:

```cpp
    JavaVMAttachArgs* args;
    args->version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
```

Your **args** is a pointer and is not initialized. It invokes undefined behavior, is most likely to crash.
Also you are trying to delete it uninitialized:

```cpp
    delete args;
```

Also I don't understand this piece of code:

```
    JNIEnv* lEnv;
    ...
    int getEnvResult = gJvm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(lEnv), ...
```

What is the sense of **reinterpret_cast** here? By definition of the function there is required a pointer to pointer, not a cast:

```cpp
    JNIEnv* lEnv;
    ...
    int getEnvResult = gJvm->GetEnv(&lEnv, ...
```

Ok, you can cast it, but you should pass pointer to pointer here, so cast a pointer to pointer `static_cast<void**>(&lEnv)`, but it is probably not required.